# vb.net Programm much slower on Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

I have the following Problem.

I wrote a vb.net Program which interacts with an external Program (Femap by Siemens) by it´s API. The Program was fine on Windows 7. But a few month ago, the customer had to change to Windows 10. The execution time of the Program can be very long. On the test Systems the execution time was about 30 minutes, on the productive system the execution time can be up to 18 hours. So, that was fine on Windows 7. After the update to Windows 10 the execution time is nearly doubled, and this is of course not good. I already asked on a Forum of the external Program and they said, that this is not a problem of the external Pogram.  I search a long time, if the problem is the OS (found one approach - change the StackTrace) but did not really change the calculation time.

My program was originally compiled to .net framework v4.6.1. When we compiled it to v4.8 the execution time is about 10% better.

So, has anyone any ideas, what the problem could be? Are there any security issues with Windows 10 (I don´t think the program is signed by a certificate).

I would thank you a lot, if anyone has any ideas what the problem is, or how we can speed up the execution time.

Thank you, a lot.
Greetings from Austria.
Ewii

Comment: You're expecting us to have psychic ability or guess. Neither are acceptable on this site. You need to do some testing, debugging and profiling and work out where the time is being taken. Once you know specifics, then you can ask specific questions.

Comment: if most of the processing is done by Femap, then it could be that Femap is slower. Some profiling will be needed to find where most of the time is spent